# request django token msg: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm trying to get a token from the Django authentication.
But I'm getting following error:

```
Exception type: <class 'AttributeError'> msg: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

My test code snippet looks like this:

```
import os
import requests
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

BASE_DEV_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:4000"


def login(url=(BASE_DEV_URL + "/api/user/token")):

    headers = {
        'accept: application/json',
        'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type:' 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }

    try:
        payload = {"email": os.getenv('TEST_USER_NAME'), "password": os.getenv('TEST_USER_PASSWORD')}
        print(payload)
        res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        print(f'####### {type(res)}')
    except Exception as e:
        return f'Exception type: {type(e)} msg: {e}'

    return res


response = login()

print(response)
```

However, when I test it with swagger with curl command it works fine
curl looks like this

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/user/token/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'X-CSRFTOKEN: T7wW385wMiYDERJU2yWvqGorrbKjtb9zhWqlAkAlE30QKgP7DoQMbc7MnQT3UAti' \
  -d 'email=test%40example.com&password=123XVW174'
```

Any idea how to make it work.
I'm not sure, but it may because by serialized.
I worked with request library a lot and never encountered such error.
Will be grateful for any advice which could solve it.

Comment: `headers` is a set and not a dict, you need to quote the key and value separately - `'accept': 'application/json'`

Answer (score 1):

Your headers should be a dictionary, not a set, so:

```
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
```

Comment: I tried this however, I get error 500 then ```RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:4000/api/user/token/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
[25/Sep/2022 20:21:49] "POST /api/user/token HTTP/1.1" 500 62041
 ```

Comment: @Michal: you should not `json.dumps` the content in the data...

Comment: @Michal: furthermore, as the error says, you should append a trailing slash, so `url=f"{BASE_DEV_URL}/api/user/token/"`

Comment: I tried withou json.dumps same 500 error. I must add that app is started by docker compose and test is run from local project

Comment: @Michal: read the error, you need to add a trailing slash to the url... The header also needs an CSRFTOKEN...

Comment: I added from django.middleware.csrf import get_token and changed request to  res = get_token(requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)) Now I'm getting error Exception type: <class 'AttributeError'> msg: 'Response' object has no attribute 'META'

Comment: Is there any way to disable CRF token. Or function to generate it. Still can't figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up disabling crfs from middleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

My headers and request look like this:

```
headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'multipart': 'form-data',
    }

payload = {"email": os.getenv('TEST_USER_NAME'), "password": os.getenv('TEST_USER_PASSWORD')}

 res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

It finally gives me response 200 and proper data.
However, I would like to know how to properly generate crf token for testing